# 'Invalid syntax error' when linking user input to run a set function(Python)

Tags: python

I'm trying to set up a 'Fahrenheit to Celsius' and 'Celsius to Fahrenheit' calculator that would allow the user to select if they want Celsius converted to Fahrenheit or visa versa but I'm getting an invalid syntax error and I'm not quite sure why.[The code I'm using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmZRZ.png)// [The 'Invalid Syntax Error'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBY4p.png)
I understand the problem could be pretty basic, I'm relatively new to python just.

```
CelsiusorFarenheit = input("Would you like Celsius to Farenheit or Farenheit
to Celcius?")
if CelsiusorFarenheit == "celsius" or "Celsius":
 def Celsius():
  centToFaren = int(input("Enter a temperature in Celsius: "))
  Farenheit= 9.0/5.0 * centToFaren+32
  print ("Temperature:", centToFaren, "Celsius =", Farenheit, "F")
else CelsiusorFarenheit == "farenheit" or "Farenheit":
 def Farenheit():
  farenToCent = int(Input("Enter a temperature in Farenheit: "))
  Celcius=(farenToCent-32)*5.0/9.0
  print("Temperature:", centToFaren, "Fahrenheit =", Celcius, "C")
```

Comment: Ahh I see, would make sense.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You are putting a condition in an `else` block, which is a syntax error. `else` blocks are executed when no other condition matches so they cannot have conditions. You can change it to an `elif` statement or remove the condition. So change this line:

```
else CelsiusorFarenheit == "farenheit" or "Farenheit":
```

to either this:

```
elif CelsiusorFarenheit.lower() == "farenheit":
```

or this:

```
else:
```

Comment: This would have also fixed the issue I was having, thanks for your help!

Comment: Always happy to help :)

Comment: `elif CelsiusorFarenheit == "farenheit" or "Farenheit":` probably doesn't do what you think it does: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value

Comment: This does indeed solve the error message, but it does not explain the wrong logic behind the statement and does not address other things that could be improved in the code

Answer (score 4):

There are a few points i notice from the above code.

To resolve the syntax error, you will need to update the `else` to an `elif` followed by the condition.

To improve the code 2 points further, you can call `lower()` on your variable as below

```
CelsiusorFarenheit.lower()
```

and update the comparisons to long form as below.

```
def celsius():
    centToFaren = int(input("Enter a temperature in Celsius: "))
    Farenheit= 9.0/5.0 * centToFaren+32
    print ("Temperature:", centToFaren, "Celsius =", Farenheit, "F")

def farenheit():
    farenToCent = int(Input("Enter a temperature in Farenheit: "))
    Celcius=(farenToCent-32)*5.0/9.0
    print("Temperature:", centToFaren, "Fahrenheit =", Celcius, "C")

if CelsiusorFarenheit.lower() == "celsius":
    celsius()
elif CelsiusorFarenheit.lower() == "farenheit":
    farenheit()
```

Comment: Ahh I see, I appreciate the added pointers! This has fixed the issue I had now I just need it to print both output values in two decimal values.